# MySQL IN Condition Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, where-clause, where-in

I have a question and answers listing and an option to filter the questions based on the % of correct answers. So I am using the following query for the listing :

```
SELECT 
question_id, 
text
FROM 
test_answers LEFT JOIN test_questions ON test_questions.id = test_answers.question_id 
LEFT JOIN test_categories ON test_questions.`category_id` = test_categories.id 
WHERE `question_id` IN(question IDS) 
GROUP BY `question_id` 
ORDER BY `question_id` DESC;
```

and using another query for finding the question IDS for which the % of correct answers in the given range. The query is as follows :

```
SELECT q1.question_id FROM (
        SELECT test_answers.question_id AS question_id, 
        SUM( IF( test_answers.correct_answer =1, 1, 0 ) ) AS correct_answers, 
        SUM( IF( test_answers.correct_answer !=1, 1, 0 ) ) AS incorrect_answers, 
        round( ( SUM( IF( test_answers.correct_answer =1, 1, 0 ) ) / ( SUM( IF( test_answers.correct_answer =1, 1, 0 ) ) + SUM( IF( test_answers.correct_answer !=1, 1, 0 ) ) ) *100 ) , 2 ) AS percentage 
        FROM test_replies 
        JOIN test_answers ON test_replies.answer_id = test_answers.id 
        GROUP BY test_answers.question_id 
        HAVING percentage between 80 and 89 AND correct_answers >25
) AS q1
```

Now the issue is that the second query returns almost 4000 question Ids and it will increase in the near future and might be become 10k or more. So I seriously would like to optimize the query as it is going to impact the performance in a great deal. Can anyone suggest a better method for doing it ?

Comment: 10k for mysql is nothing ,its probably fast even without indices.

Comment: May be bu, if it become one million or more, then I think definitely it will affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

try join instead of `IN`, see if it helps. (sql not tested)

```
SELECT 
    ta.question_id, text
FROM 
    (
        SELECT test_answers.question_id AS question_id, 
        SUM( IF( test_answers.correct_answer =1, 1, 0 ) ) AS correct_answers, 
        SUM( IF( test_answers.correct_answer !=1, 1, 0 ) ) AS incorrect_answers, 
        round( ( SUM( IF( test_answers.correct_answer =1, 1, 0 ) ) / ( SUM( IF( test_answers.correct_answer =1, 1, 0 ) ) + SUM( IF( test_answers.correct_answer !=1, 1, 0 ) ) ) *100 ) , 2 ) AS percentage 
        FROM test_replies 
        JOIN test_answers ON test_replies.answer_id = test_answers.id 
        GROUP BY test_answers.question_id 
        HAVING percentage between 80 and 89 AND correct_answers >25
    ) AS q1
INNER JOIN 
    test_answers ta USING (question_id) 
LEFT JOIN 
    test_questions ON test_questions.id = ta.question_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    test_categories ON test_questions.`category_id` = test_categories.id 
GROUP BY 
    ta.question_id`
ORDER BY 
    ta.question_id DESC;
```